# Using a selectors value in a component

Tags: angular, typescript

When using a selector is there any way possible to access a property of the observable without subscribing to it? For example:

```
public selectedOrder$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getSelectedOrder);
```

Above is the selector I have. Later in my code, I am trying to access a property of that selector like below:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.routerUrl$.pipe(map(x => {
  switch (x) {
    case ('/dashboard/order/' + this.selectedOrder$.orderNumber):
    omitted code...
```

Is there a similar operator that I could use to set a variable equal to selectedOrder$.orderNumber or any other way to access this property in the code only (Note: I am not needing this in the template).

Comment: How about ``tap`` operator? Original value still will be passed because no map was used but you still can invoke some actions when new value arrives.

Comment: @Buczkowski unfortunately that is not working. Thank you though